# Unable to ssh to localhost with or without password

Tags: ssh, osx-el-capitan

I am trying to setup passwordless SSH to localhost on my macbook running OS X El Capitan [Version 10.11.6]. While trying public key based SSH it says connection closed by 127.0.0.1. While trying with password, it continues to prompt for password, even though I am entering the password. I tried seeing old posts of adding the key to the keychain, but that didn't work for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3664055?start=0&tstart=0, so I need to whitelist who can do a remote login.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.